# sessionStorage doesn't update the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, session-storage

I'm trying to reduce my navbar with a "isCollapse" variable in my sessionStorage.
By clicking the button, my sessionStorage change, but the render doesn't update.

> **JSX Code**

```
{
    sessionStorage.getItem("collapse") === "true" ?
    <div className="LeftMenu" style={{
        width: 45,
        float: "left",
        height: "100%",
        borderRight: "1px solid #dfe4e8",
        textAlign: "left",
    }}>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTasks} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUsers} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTh} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArchive} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCopy} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faNewspaper} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDownload} className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFingerprint} className="icon" />
        </div>

    </div>
    :
    <div className="LeftMenu" style={{
        width: "12%",
        float: "left",
        height: "100%",
        borderRight: "1px solid #dfe4e8",
        textAlign: "left",
        minWidth: 200
    }}>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} className="icon" /> Home
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTasks} className="icon" /> Organisations
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUsers} className="icon" /> Users
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTh} className="icon" /> Templates Library
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArchive} className="icon" /> Audit Trail
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCopy} className="icon" /> Data Copy
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faNewspaper} className="icon" /> VAT Reporting
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDownload} className="icon" /> Download add-in
        </div>
        <div className="tableElement">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFingerprint} className="icon" /> Account
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but if I set the sessionStorage to true and I refresh manually, it works.

**edit 1:** I tried to use the ComponentDidMount function like this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
        isCollapse: sessionStorage.getItem("collapse")
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.isCollapse) })
}
```

but it doesn't work too

**edit 2:** I did not specify but my onClick function and my render aren't in the save file, I have the button to reduce the sidebar in another component, and I want to keep this change in all my website that's why I use the sessionStorage

Comment: Session storage is not state. Why would it rerender components?

Comment: Component will not update if `props` or `state` don't change.

Comment: Are you putting this code in componentDidMount() ?

Comment: this code is in the render, but i tried to set my variable in the state, doesn't work too :   `componentDidMount = () => {
      this.setState({
          isCollapse: sessionStorage.getItem("collapse")
      },() => {console.log(this.state.isCollapse)})
  }`

Comment: try putting this in componentDidMount(). It will show the old state first but due to componentDidMount() it will update its state fast.

Comment: You could do something like : componentDidMount() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('collapse') === 'true'){ this.setState({ isCollapse: true }) } else { this.setState({ isCollapse: false }) } }

Comment: @AnthonyBrochier well `componentDidMount` is only run once, when the component mounts. It won't react if the session storage is updated _after_ the component has mounted, if that's what's happening

Comment: @YatinGaikwad if i put a console.log in my componentDidMount function, nothing appear in the console so I think there is a problem with it

Comment: @Jayce444 so how can I update my render ?

Comment: onClick={() => this.setState({ You need to update the state here })

Comment: @YatinGaikwad I did not specify but my onClick function and my render aren't in the save file, I have the button to reduce the sidebar in an another component, and I want to keep this change in all my website that's why I use the sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

You could use reducer or state to store the changes as render will occur if there is a change in state or props. The sessionStorage change will not trigger render. Note using session storage is bad practice for this requirement.

```
//initialize a state

state = {
collapse:false
}

//set state on click
onClick={() => this.setState({collapse:!this.state.collapse})

//use state to show and hide

{this.state.collapse && <...content/>}
```

if you are using reducer, do the following steps

```
1.create an action creators
2.dispatch an action
3.set state in store
4.connect state to the component diretly or by passing props
```

Comment: I tried to put it in the state with : `componentDidMount = () => {
      this.setState({
          isCollapse: sessionStorage.getItem("collapse")
      },() => {console.log(this.state.isCollapse)})
  }` but it doesn't work too

Comment: @AnthonyBrochier I have made some changes in the answer, you could try the same method.

Comment: I did not specify but my onClick function and my render aren't in the save file, I have the button to reduce the sidebar in an another component, and I want to keep this change in all my website that's why I use the sessionStorage

Comment: please use reducer and make state global.

Answer (score 0):

render() method will render this code but it won't update the state you need to use setState, you can create a function which will check the previous state if the isCollapse is true it will make it false and if it set to false it will make it true, so it will act as a trigger button that will make your isCollapse true or false depending on the previous value.

```
changeIsCollapse() {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('collapse') === 'true')
  { 
   this.setState({ 
    isCollapse: false
   }) 
  } else { 
   this.setState({ 
    isCollapse: true
  }) 
 }
}
```

and inside in onClick of your button you can call this function

```
onClick={this.changeIsCollapse.bind(this)}
```

Comment: You can also update the sessionStorage by sessionStorage.setItem() inside those 'if' and 'else'